# Delay in gear upshift on high rev

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, camry, throttle-position-sensor

I've noticed my Toyota Camry 2010 (automatic transmission) delays gear upshift on high engine rev (> 4000 RPM). But on low rev (typically below 3000 RPM) gear upshift is timely. This wasn't case when I bought it (used).

This problem would usually drive my engine to more than 6000 RPM and sometimes without a gear up shift until I start to ease on the gas pedal (throttle). I ran a diagnosis via the OBD-II port and everything checked out fine.

I read somewhere on the internet that sometimes high current from the throttle can cause the shift solenoid to not function properly. But this didn't show on the scan.

Questions:

1. Is there a way of testing the gas pedal (throttle) to know if it's giving out excess current?
2. Based on the problem described, might anyone suggest a possible solution or a way to find out the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the auto trans? Fluid ie level, age? Serviced? Has this car been well looked after? Thrashed to within an inch of its life? Where did you read about the tps? Please update your question with the detail and don’t leave it in comments.

Comment: Re #1: Gas pedal is a voltage-based sensor, hence the output is voltage and not current. The voltage returned by it can be checked with OBD2 diagnostic tool.